# Angularjs: get service name from within service

Tags: angularjs

How can I get the name of a `service` (or `factory`, `provider`, `controller`, `directive`...) from WITHIN the object?  Eg

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('myCtrl', function() {
  // how do I get the name 'myCtrl' here?
})
```

The obvious way is hard coding, but I want to avoid that

```
.service('myService', function() {
  this.name = 'myService';
});
```

I guess this is a way, but I'm hoping to avoid it as I don't want to have to declare globals in my app

```
var myCtrlName = 'myCtrl';
angular.module('app', []).controller(myCtrlName, function() {
  console.log(myCtrlName);
});
```

Comment: Why do you even need this? The moment you depend on names in your code you'll run into problems.

Comment: @Yoshi I want to use it to register callbacks with a mediator service. I pass the name of the service to the mediator in an .init so the mediator has an id for each service. Mediator connects endpoints a bit like `$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl:'views/main.html',controller: 'myCtrl',...})`, which also relies on names, and is an accepted (indeed celebrated) pattern in Angular. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Angulars use of names always relys on the fact that at one time the element in question was registered under that specific name. It's never guessed or similar, it's always a setter/getter relationship. I'm not sure whether what you're trying to do is the same concept. Also from your comment with regards to your question, this looks like a [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @Yoshi :D Yes, possibly an X-Y Problem. I've already built a successful "X" without too much fumbling (I think!). I just wanted to remove the hard coded names ("Y").

Answer (score 2):

Define your service name as a variable so you can reuse, then wrap in a closure to avoid creating a global variable.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
(function () {
    var serviceName = "myService";
    app.service(serviceName, function () {
        this.name = serviceName;
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is how to do it, but be aware, it's very dirty and it uses undocumented stuff from angular :D

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, Serv) {

});
app.service("Serv", function() {
  //We're gonna compare functions, the current one and the one registered in the invokeQueue of the app
  var callee= arguments.callee;
  //Loop the invokeQueue 
  _.each(app._invokeQueue, function(inv) {
    //Check if the functions match
    if(inv[2][1] === callee) {
      //Print the name of the current service!
      console.log(inv[2][0]);
    }
  });
});
```

Check this jsbin to see it in action:
http://jsbin.com/yugogonoya/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Too dirty to accept as the answer, but +1 for your ingenuity. I would love to have you on my team. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, that it's not possible to get service/factory name.

If we are talking about **controller** name, it's possible with subscription on `$routeChangeSuccess` event.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
     console.log($route.current.controller);
});
```

Also, if we are talking about **directive**. You can use this trick.

```
app.directive('directiveOne', function (){
  return {
    controller: 'SomeCtrl',
    scope: true,
    template: '<button ng-click="myFun()">Test A</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.directiveName = 'directiveOne';
    }
  };
});

app.directive('directiveTwo', function (){
  return {
    controller: 'SomeCtrl',
    scope: true,
    template: '<button ng-click="myFun()">Test B</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.directiveName = 'directiveTwo';
    }
  };
});

app.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope){
    var ctrl = this;
    $scope.test = function (){
       console.log('Directive name is: ' + ctrl.directiveName);
    };
});
```

Comment: Re your directive trick, it's always possible to hard code the name of a service the same way `angular.module('app', []).service('myService', function() { this.name = 'myService' })`. That's the other method I'm trying to avoid (just added to my question!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui-router you can learn the name of the controller through $state service.

```
$state.current.controller;
```